# Making div a clickable link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP search script that parses results into HTML div elements to make styling the results easier. I have the following code:

```
<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['title']}</a></div><div class='url'>{$row['url']}</div><div class='desc'>{$row['description']}</div></div>
```

I want to make it so when a the whole webresult div is clicked on, it goes to the url of the result.

I hope people can understand what I'm trying to describe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to make the entire div clickable, try to style the `<a>` element as a block element and make its size equivalent to the parent `<div>`, i.e.,

```
.title a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 yes @Callum Whyte if you set `display: block;` on your link it will act like a `<div>` and you can style it to your liking. Using javascript to make a div act like a link is just not SEO friendly, and IMO it should be avoided.

Comment: This is definitely the preferred way.  Using JavaScript to make a div clickable stops the ability to open in new tab or window.  A feature many users use often use.

Comment: Yes, avoid divitis (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitis) by using display: block. I'd wager some of your other divs are also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery:

```
$('.webresult').click(function() {
   window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: do you have jQuery loaded in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Best to do this via javascript. If using jQuery, you could do this:

```
$('.webresult').click(function(){
    $('this').find('a').click();
})
```

Comment: On the first line here it should be `$(".webresult")` (missed the period out).

Comment: @jack: thanks for catching that! @callum: it's jQuery. You would first load the jQuery library, and then use the above. If this is the only JS you are using on the page, then jQuery is overkill, of course.

Answer (score 1):

isn't

```
<div onclick="location.href='/the_url/'">
```

what you need?

Comment: I know this is 10 years old but exactly what I needed, cheers @Headcrab

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the anchor around everything instead of just the row title, and set it to `display: block;` in css. Further style the anchor the way you previously styled the div, and drop the div altogether. You probably also want to set the text color (including for :hover) and remove the underline using the text-decoration property.

If you decide to go with one of the javascript options the others posted, make sure you have a graceful fallback. Not everyone has javascript enabled.

Comment: Also, as a web developer, I have to admit I blame others of incompetence when they use javascript for something css can do just fine.

Comment: You can't put anchors around div elements to pass W3 validation.

Comment: @imoda: Exactly. Hence the "drop the div altogether".

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with jQuery:

```
$(".webresult").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Another solution is that within the HTML 5 spec, block elements can actually be links to other places. You can read more about that here: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/